# Downgrading iPhone 3G 4.1 to 3.X or 2.X

Tags: iphone

my iPhone 3G with iOS 4.1 is really slow and I am tired of this stupid situation. I am considering downgrading somehow to old 3.X or even 2.X versions, so it can breath again. What do you think? How would yo do it and to what iOs version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you don't use spotlight (the search screen when you swipe right from Home) you can turn that off which should increase the performance of the iPhone.
Settings>General>Spotlight Search and then deselect all of the options.

If you still want to downgrade....

The iPhone isn't really designed to downgrade but there are ways to do it.

I had to down grade from the 4.0beta to 3.1.3 and followed [this guide](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/09/tuaw-how-to-downgrading-your-3-1-3-iphone-to-3-1-2/) on The Unofficial Apple Weblog.

Comment: The correct path to the Spotlight Search is Settings->General->Home Button->Spotlight Search

Comment: I think this is version specific. Certainly, on my phone running 4.1 it is as I wrote above.